# Who among 20th and 21st century Aristotelians has the most citations?

Tags: aristotle, contemporary-philosophy

Who among 20<sup>th</sup> and 21<sup>st</sup> century Aristotelians is the most influential in terms of citations? And through what are they cited the most?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more like a question for academiaSE

Comment: I don't actually see how it's a question that's fit for academia.se per se. The current form is based on changes through conversation about "most influential" questions which I'm hoping we can avoid.

Comment: If you don't give a hoot about quality of "citations," probably Ayn Rand or Mortimer Adler. I would actually like to know a proper answer to this but don't know where to look.

Comment: Who counts as an Aristotelian? I've heard the term peripatetic mentioned in connection with a few philosophers; there's also a theological connection as well.